# How to center tcl/tk window respecting workarea size?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I trying to place window at center on my desktop. But I could not find the way how to find height/width of work area (i.e. respect taskbar or other system's areas).

My first attempt was:

```
wm withdraw $window
update idletasks

set width  [winfo reqwidth  $window]
set height [winfo reqheight $window]

set x [expr { ([winfo screenwidth $window] - $width) / 2}]
set y [expr { ([winfo screenheight $window] - $height) / 2}]

wm geometry $window ${width}x${height}+${x}+${y}
wm deiconify $window
```

But it doesn't work correctly because `winfo screenwidth/height` returns values based on screen resolution, but not on desktop work area.

My another attempt was from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36387629/1980049

```
wm withdraw $window
update idletasks

set width  [winfo reqwidth  $window]
set height [winfo reqheight $window]

toplevel [set testWin ".__test_screen_size__[incr UID]"]
wm withdraw $testWin
wm state $testWin zoomed
update idletasks
set x [expr { ([winfo width $testWin] - $width) / 2 }]
set y [expr { ([winfo height $testWin] - $height) / 2 }]
destroy $testWin

wm geometry $window ${width}x${height}+${x}+${y}
wm deiconify $window
```

It works as expected and correct x/y values were obtained. But the `$testWin` blinked on screen, so this method also not suitable. Without `update idletasks` it doesn't work also.

Comment: What operating system? What window manager?

Comment: I want to find a platform-independent and portable solution. On Windows, I can get these values using ```twapi``` module and ```set workarea [twapi::get_display_monitor_info [twapi::get_display_monitor_from_window $window -default nearest]]```.

Comment: There is no platform independent solution.   All of the different window managers on the various operating systems are different.    Some have bugs.   I have a work-around in my code due to Xfce on Linux.  The best way may be to have a setup task that "blinks", run it once only.  Save the data.  If the user changes their screen or setup, it will have to be run again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
winfo screenmmheight .
```

Returns a decimal string giving the height of window's screen, in millimeters.

```
winfo screenmmwidth .
```

Returns a decimal string giving the width of window's screen, in millimeters.

Answer (score 0):

```
package require Tk

set window_1_width 350 ;    set window_1_height 250

set x_1 [ expr {([ winfo vrootwidth  . ] - $window_1_width ) / 2 }]
set y_1 [ expr {([ winfo vrootheight . ] - $window_1_height ) / 2 }]
wm geometry . ${window_1_width}x${window_1_height}+$x_1+$y_1
```

tested on windows 7  tcl/tk 8.6